# What does oop mean in JVM crash report?

Tags: java, jvm, terminology, crash-reports, jvm-crash

I have a JVM crash report and there're lines that say `R13=0x00000007a22ba2fc is an oop`

What exactly is an oop? Is it an object?

Comment: ordinary object pointer

Comment: Damn! should've known!
Somebody should vote down my question! =.=!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: *Ordinary Object Pointer* according to the [official documentation](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html#oop) of the *Java Development Kit*.

> An object pointer. Specifically, a pointer into the GC-managed heap. (The term is traditional. One 'o' may stand for 'ordinary'.) Implemented as a native machine address, not a handle. Oops may be directly manipulated by compiled or interpreted Java code, because the GC knows about the liveness and location of oops within such code. (See GC map.) Oops can also be directly manipulated by short spans of C/C++ code, but must be kept by such code within handles across every safepoint.